# When converting a framework to a Swift Package, where do I put the information normally provided by the Info.plist and by the .xcodeproj files?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to convert an iOS framework project to a Swift Package.
Normally a great deal of information regarding the project are stored either in the `Info.plist` and in the `.xcodeproj` file.

It is not clear to me where and how I can configure the Swift Package because Xcode won't build the package if there's an info.plist file. it throws this error: "Cannot build xxx without a run destination.  Select a run destination to perform this action".
What?

But there are lots of necessary info.plist entries essential to have an app working.
Anybody can help please?

Comment: You got things confused here. An iOS app uses the Info.plist to get the strings needed to ask for camera permissions, not the framework. You can have all your logic inside the Swift Package but the NSCameraUsageDescription value will always come from the Info.plist of the app where the framework is imported.

Comment: Ok, I made the wrong example and I`ll remove it. But the still where can I can save the build settings and all the other values that normally goes in the info.plist and  in the project file?